# How to solve for the area for quadrilaterals like these?

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

How do I solve for the area of the yellow quadrilateral? This question has been bugging me and I haven't been able to figure out much given the areas of the triangles, 2 and 3 and the quadrilateral at the bottom, 20

[image]

Comment: If you're stuck, where does this problem come from, and can you think of any facts related to the problem? See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more information.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the same problem as the problem from Presh Talwalkar from the YouTube channel [MindYourDecisions](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2018/03/08/can-you-solve-a-5th-grade-math-problem-from-china-to-identify-talented-students/), just with different numbers.

Comment: please show your attempts

Comment: @TobyMak Great. I didn't think you'd be so quick to know this link.

Comment: @TobyMak sorry for posting a similar question. Also thank you for pointing out the resemblance to the video. After doing the same working, I managed to get an answer of 25!

Comment: No worries. It's nice that you found the answer to your own question!

Answer (score 3):

I'll write an answer so that this question can be marked as 'answered'.

[image]

We know that: $$\Delta DNA = \Delta DCN + \Delta NAB = \Delta DCM = \Delta DAM + \Delta MCB = \frac{1}{2} (\text{area of ABCD}).$$

Now from $\Delta DCN + \Delta NAB = \Delta DCM$, we get: $\Delta DCP + 2 + 3 + \Delta RQM + 20$$ = \Delta DCP + DPQR + \Delta RQM$, and after cancelling like terms, we get directly: $25 = DPQR$.

Hence $\boxed{25}$ is the area of the shaded region in yellow.